# How to order dict's keys with different types of values in python

Tags: python, dictionary

face the next problem: I need some hints on how to order dict by keys and values, but values can be different types, as example:

```
some_dict = {
'list_from_one_element': ['one'], 
'list_from_many_elements': ['one', 'three', 'two'],
     'dict_with_dicts':
         {
             'first': '1',
             'third': '3'
             'second': '2',
         },
```

}

So, in the end I need smt like this:

```
dict_items([('dict_with_dicts', {'first': '1', 'second': '2', 'third': '3'}), ('list_from_many_elements', ['one', 'two', 'three']), ('list_from_one_element', ['one'])])
```

I tried to make this in for loop like this:

```
sorted_dict = dict()
for key in sorted(some_dict):
    for value in some_dict.values():
        sorted_dict.update({key: sorted(value)})
for key in sorted_dict.get('dict_with_dicts'):
    sorted_dict.get('dict_with_dicts').update({key: dict_with_dicts.get(key)})
```

But is there any way to make it beautiful?

Comment: You should not worry about ordering the keys in a dictionary.  A dictionary should be thought of as being unordered, like an SQL query.  Why do you care about this?

Comment: What if I want to compare two dicts, and I need to format them to the same style? For example key 'username' in the first dict is the third element, but in the second it is the fifth, and if I want to compare them via '==' operator, I will receive False as 'username' is in different places. So I should format them and check if this key exist, and does this key has the same value as in other dict

Comment: Order doesn't matter:  `{'a':1, 'b':2} == {'b':2, 'a':1}` -> `True`, or if just comparing one key, `dict1['username'] == dict2['username']` doesn't care about the *location* of `username` in the dictionaries, only that the *value* matches.

Comment: Yes, here the deal. What if we do next: some_dict_1 = {'some_list_1': ['one', 'two'], 'some_dict_with_dicts': {'one': '1', 'two': '2'}} and some_dict_2 = {'some_list_2': ['two', 'one'], 'some_dixt_with_dicts': {'two': '2', 'one': '1'}}. If you try to compare them, you will receive False, even the data is the same, just not ordered

Comment: Dicts are not formatted.  There is no "third element" and "fifth element".  You just check, for all the keys in dict1, is that key in dict2, and vice versa.  If you insist, you can do `key1 = list(dict1)`, then sort the `key1` list and compare those.  Indeed, I would assert that the two dicts in your example are not the same.

Comment: The problem in your example (apart of one key being different) is that you have a list as value, and lists are ordered.

Comment: Yep, you are right I see now https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/#:~:text=are%20as%20follows%3A-,Lists%20are%20ordered.,-Lists%20can%20contain

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the lists by sets, it actually returns true (I corrected what I assumed spelling mistakes in your example, because else the dictionaries are truly different):

```
some_dict_1 = {
    'some_list_1': {'one', 'two'},
    'some_dict_with_dicts': {
        'one': '1',
        'two': '2'
        }
    } 
    some_dict_2 = {
        'some_list_1': {'two', 'one'},
        'some_dict_with_dicts': {
            'two': '2',
            'one': '1'
        }
    }

print(some_dict_1 == some_dict_2)  # -> True
```

However, dicts in recent python versions are ordered in that the order of items being reproduced is defined as by insertion:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping

> Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion
> order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

I had a similar issue once, because I needed to flatten a nested dictionary and make a list out of the values. Then I used something like this:

```
def sort_recursive(d):
    try:
        items = d.items()
    except AttributeError:
        return d
    return {k: sort_recursive(v) for k, v in sorted(items)}


print(sort_recursive(some_dict_1))
```

But again, for your purposes, I think you don't need it.